# How to rig a Seatbelt? (Buckle passing through seatbelt)

Tags: rigging, armature, bezier-curves

I am having some trouble with rigging a seatbelt. I want to create a rig where the seatbelt reacts to the movement of the seatbelt buckle. As the buckle would move (Up and down for example), the seatbelt should move with it and pass through the buckle attribute accordingly.

I really couldn't find any info on especially objects/rigs sliding or passing eachother.

See blend. file which I included.

https://pasteall.org/blend/246862150d814f40b4509414c372ff1a

Thank you so much in advance!

Cheers,
Sander

Answer (score 13):

You could do it with **Lattice**:

- Bring back your belt to a flat plane:

[image]

- Create a lattice,  in the *Properties panel > Object Data* choose its *Resolution* (here 2/1/5), in *Object* mode, scale it down, rotate it so that it frames the area that you need to tweak. Give your belt a *Lattice* modifier and choose the lattice as *Object*.

[image]

- In *Edit* mode, move the vertices of the lattice so that it tweaks the belt the way you want. Parent the lattice to the buckle so that when you'll move the buckle, the lattice will follow and tweak the belt:

[image]